# Filtering a regular expression in string with Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a javascript string with some contact information I would like to filter. In example, if an email or phone is written, these should be replaced with a mask.

I´m trying to do something like:

```
function(message) {
            var filteredMessage = message.replace("/^([\da-z_\.-]+)@([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})$/", "<Email>");
            return filteredMessage;
        }
```

but this is not working.

Comment: Is your question about the function above or the regular expression to do the task? Please define "not working".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
function filterMessage(message) {
        var m = message.replace(/[\da-z_\.-]+@[\da-z\.-]+\.[a-z\.]{2,6}/, "<Email>");
        return m;
    }


alert(filterMessage("Your Email: bla@fasel.de lorem Ipsum dolor"));
```

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ochxdkam/

Issues with your script:

- No function name
- Regular Expression in `"`, must be without

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function filterMessage(message) {
    //var reg = /^([\da-z_\.-]+)@([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})$/;
    var reg = /\b(\S+@\S+\.\S+)\b/g;
    var filteredMessage = message.replace(reg, "<Email>");
    return filteredMessage;
}

filterMessage("email.example.com will be replaced, so will be next@example.com");
```

or you could use this regExp: `/\b(\S+@\S+\.\S+)\b/g` (from Kieran Pot's answer) and then you could use your function to do a little better filtering.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use a very loose regex to search for email addresses, because there are so many variations in how email addresses are formatted. You might try, for example:

```
/\S+@\S+\.\S+/
```

This will match a@b.c where one or more non-whitespace characters are allowed in place of a, b, and c.

You could use this in place of the regex in strah's answer, just posted.

Comment: I have used OP's regex :-)